# HTML5 geolocation to display driving Time between 2 locations?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use HTML5 gelocation in my project. so far so good but 1 thing that I am struggling with is the fact that I cannot get driving time between two different locations.

well, to be exact, I can get the time in hours, minutes but it seems that i need to use Google map for this which i don't want to!

Here is a working fiddle with a map: http://jsfiddle.net/qa8pcyj9/

Or you can view it [HERE](http://robertnyman.com/html5/geolocation/current-location-and-directions.html)

here is the code:

```
(function () {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(),
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(),
        createMap = function (start) {
            var travel = {
                    origin : (start.coords)? new google.maps.LatLng(start.lat, start.lng) : start.address,
                    destination : "Alexanderplatz, Berlin",
                    travelMode : google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                    // Exchanging DRIVING to WALKING above can prove quite amusing <img src="http://robertnyman.com/wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_smile.gif" alt=":-)" class="wp-smiley">
                },
                mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 10,
                    // Default view: downtown Stockholm
                    center : new google.maps.LatLng(59.3325215, 18.0643818),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("map-directions"));
            directionsService.route(travel, function(result, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                }
            });
        };

        // Check for geolocation support    
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                    // Success!
                    createMap({
                        coords : true,
                        lat : position.coords.latitude,
                        lng : position.coords.longitude
                    });
                }, 
                function () {
                    // Gelocation fallback: Defaults to Stockholm, Sweden
                    createMap({
                        coords : false,
                        address : "Sveavägen, Stockholm"
                    });
                }
            );
        }
        else {
            // No geolocation fallback: Defaults to Lisbon, Portugal
            createMap({
                coords : false,
                address : "Lisbon, Portugal"
            });
        }
})();
```

if you look at the top of the driving direction Texts, you will see the Time is shown in hours.

so that is basically what I need But i only need that without all the rest of the stuff like the map, driving directions etc etc.

**Question:**

is it possible to get the driving time between each gelocation without the use of Google map and without displaying all the driving instructions etc?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: geolocation does 1 thing only: tell you the coordinates of where you are.  All the rest is Google Maps services.  Google is very clear, the terms & conditions say you have to display the map on your page if you want to use their services.

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay, So do you think I will be going against their TOS if I display the map on my page but set the width/height to 1px so its almost invisible?

Comment: I don't know exactly.  Of course technically it is possible; it is clearly not what Google intends, but I don't know how far exactly you can go.